# Cygwin and MinGW

Tags: cygwin

I'm trying to make a decision about whether to install Cygwin. I'm currently using the TDM-GCC 64Bit compiler on Windows 7.

Due to a few ridiculous build issues whenever I build something on Windows (libraries etc) I wanted to confirm that some of my assumptions are correct.  I have looked at their website and a number of forum posts but still aren't sure I have a complete grasp of what it does.  Could anyone confirm or deny the below.

1 - Cygwin provides a set of tools GNU tools etc which can be utilized to compile programs, create makefiles, much more, etc.

2 - Cygwin also provides a command line interface for building programs (unix like)?

3 - Cygwin provides a compatibility layer which emulates a unix like or posix framework?

4 - If I have Cygwin I don't need to use my TDM-GCC 64bit compiler  as Cygwin provides it's own compiler. (What is this compiler called, I'm not sure)?

5 -  If I compile a program in c++ using Cygwin on Windows, can I run that binary on a PC with windows installed even if Cygwin is not installed on that pc?

Thanks, I realize these are menial questions but the Cygwin mailing lists take weeks to respond to questions so I thought I would ask the programming community instead..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1: Yes

2: Yes, default bash but other are also available

3: yes

4: GCC . It is also possible to install a gcc cross compiler from cygwin to mingw64.

5: In theory yes but you need to pack all needed libraries. So it is not recommended. For that you can use the cross compiler.